"Docker compose --build" taking way longer than "docker build" and then failing to build
EDIT: After David Maze's comment I found out the problem was I had written my "context" and "dockerfile" lines wrong so the docker build command launched by compose was docker build . -f ./source_folder/Dockerfile instead of docker build ./source_folder -f ./source_folder/Dockerfile. Since I have the compose.yaml file in the parent folder of source_folder, these lines should have been:
 context: ./source_folder/
 dockerfile: ./Dockerfile

After changing them everything started working correctly, it seems that everything was caused by trying to build the parent folder instead of source_folder.

Working with Docker Desktop v4.30 for Windows in Windows 10. Docker is using WSL integration. I'm trying to get docker compose to build the image of a project instead of having to manually build them every time. The image builds correctly from PowerShell with docker build -t image_name ./source_folder in less than 20 seconds, the output is:
[+] Building 16.3s (14/14) FINISHED                                                                      docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 548B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                                  0.6s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 78B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2.38kB                                                                                0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:4837c2ac8998cf172f5892fb45f229c328e4824c43c8506f8b  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/4] WORKDIR /backend                                                                          0.0s
 => [stage-1 3/4] RUN rm -rf ./*                                                                                   0.5s
 => [builder 3/7] COPY ./package.json .                                                                            0.1s
 => [builder 4/7] COPY ./package-lock.json .                                                                       0.1s
 => [builder 5/7] RUN npm set strict-ssl false                                                                     1.2s
 => [builder 6/7] RUN npm install                                                                                 12.5s
 => [builder 7/7] COPY . .                                                                                         0.1s
 => [stage-1 4/4] COPY --from=builder /backend .                                                                   0.6s
 => exporting to image                                                                                             0.5s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                            0.5s
 => => writing image sha256:f3168093f381b74a0b39decf193564105863f826590eabfbcd18166545baf699                       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/image_name:1.0

However, when trying to do it via docker compose --build the build process stays a while in "load build context", transferring about 3GB of data (compare with the previous command which transfers less than 3kB) and then fails because of something related to tar and/or unix file permissions (--verbose output):
time="2024-05-15T12:37:47+02:00" level=debug msg="using default config store \"C:\\\\Users\\\\username\\\\.docker\\\\buildx\""
[+] Building 86.3s (5/13)                                                                                docker:default
 => [backend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 548B                                                                               0.0s
 => [backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                          0.9s
 => [backend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [backend builder 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:4837c2ac8998cf172f5892fb45f229c328e4824c43  0.0s
 => ERROR [backend internal] load build context                                                                   81.6s
 => => transferring context: 2.80GB                                                                               81.6s
------
 > [backend internal] load build context:
------
time="2024-05-15T12:37:47+02:00" level=debug msg="using default config store \"C:\\\\Users\\\\username\\\\.docker\\\\buildx\""
time="2024-05-15T12:37:47+02:00" level=debug msg="serving grpc connection"
time="2024-05-15T12:37:47+02:00" level=debug msg="stopping session" span="load buildkit capabilities"
time="2024-05-15T12:37:48+02:00" level=debug msg="stopping session"
time="2024-05-15T12:37:48+02:00" level=debug msg="serving grpc connection"
time="2024-05-15T12:37:48+02:00" level=debug msg="serving grpc connection"
time="2024-05-15T12:39:14+02:00" level=debug msg="stopping session"
failed to solve: archive/tar: unknown file mode ?rwxr-xr-x

Following some comments on github and here on SO of people having similar problems I tried doing it running the docker compose --build command from WSL itself, which managed to finish transferring the context (after almost 900 seconds!) but then failed because it couldn't find the package-lock.json and/or package.json files:
DEBU[0000] Enabled Docker Desktop integration (experimental) @ unix:///var/run/docker-cli.sock
WARN[0000] /home/username/project_folder/compose.yaml: `version` is obsolete
DEBU[0000] using default config store "/home/username/.docker/buildx"
[+] Building 870.7s (8/13)                                                                               docker:default
 => [backend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 548B                                                                               0.0s
 => [backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                          0.5s
 => [backend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [backend builder 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:4837c2ac8998cf172f5892fb45f229c328e4824c43  0.0s
 => [backend internal] load build context                                                                        869.5s
 => => transferring context: 2.81GB                                                                              869.1s
 => CACHED [backend builder 2/7] WORKDIR /backend                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [backend builder 3/7] COPY ./package.json .                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [backend builder 4/7] COPY ./package-lock.json .                                                         0.0s
------
 > [backend builder 3/7] COPY ./package.json .:
------
------
 > [backend builder 4/7] COPY ./package-lock.json .:
------
DEBU[0000] using default config store "/home/username/.docker/buildx"
DEBU[0000] stopping session                              span="load buildkit capabilities"
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection
DEBU[0000] stopping session
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection
DEBU[0871] stopping session
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 1915df6a-49bc-4b75-9a0d-2b9df49060bd::v8ypouqpyva81dnwnbkrqnysp: "/package-lock.json": not found

My source_folder is 6'5MB, there isn't a node_modules folder (and even if there was, it's listed in my .dockerignore file), so I don't know where the 3GB are coming from.
My Dockerfile is as follows:
FROM node:18-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /backend
COPY ./package.json .
COPY ./package-lock.json .
RUN npm set strict-ssl false
RUN npm install
COPY . .

FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /backend
RUN rm -rf ./*
COPY --from=builder /backend .

EXPOSE 3977

CMD ["npm", "start"]

My compose.yaml is:
version: "2.23"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./source_folder/Dockerfile
    container_name: container_name
    image: image_name
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3978:3978"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    restart: always
    environment:
      - port=3978
    pull_policy: build

So what is going on here? What is docker compose --build doing differently from docker build that it requires 3 whole GB of build context? Why does it not find the package.json and package-lock.json files? Why does it fail earlier on PowerShell? I need something, anything that helps me make sense of all of this so I can understand what's going on.

Your Compose build: block is the equivalent of docker build -f ./source_folder/Dockerfile . – you're transferring the parent directory as the build context, which is substantially larger, and which changes file paths inside the Dockerfile.  Do you want build: source_folder?

Yes, that's what I want. after reading your comment I realized what the error was. That was apparently the root of every issue I was having as now everything runs properly both in PowerShell and WSL. Thanks!
